# CSS opacity not working in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I have a problem in adjusting the background opacity.

**style.css**

```
.divOpacity1 {
     position: absolute;
     z-index: 1;
     height: 2000px;
     width: 100%;
     background-color: #FFFFFF;
     top: 2px;
     left: 0px;
     opacity: 0.6;
     -moz-opacity: 0.6;
     filter: alpha(opacity =60);
     -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
     display: none;
     }
```

this code works in IE10 and IE11. But when viewed in IE8, it gives a white screen.

Comment: You have a `display:none;` property. That would make the element invisible in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

According to [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/opacity.html):

> IE compatibility note
>
> If you want opacity to work in all IE versions, the order should be:
>
> `.opaque {
>     -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)"; // first!        filter: alpha(opacity=50);// second!
>    }`
>
> If you don’t use this order, IE8-as-IE7 doesn’t apply the opacity,
>   although IE8 and a pure IE7 do.

So change the order of your rule.

```
.divOpacity1 {
     position: absolute;
     z-index: 1;
     height: 2000px;
     width: 100%;
     background-color: #FFFFFF;
     top: 2px;
     left: 0px;
     opacity: 0.6;
     -moz-opacity: 0.6;
     -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=60)";
     filter: alpha(opacity =60);
     display: none;
     }
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I tried the above code, I'm still getting a blank white screen. No change.

Comment: Try to add <!DOCTYPE html> to your html.